# React и Яндекс-Карты: ошибка 'ready' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, яндекс-карты, jest

Собственно карта работает корректно, но Jest выдаёт ошибку:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'ready' of undefined

Код:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Map extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     const {ymaps} = window;

     function init() { 
       console.log('start init');
     }
     ymaps.ready(init);
  }
}
```

Можно конечно использовать react-yandex-maps или react-load-script, но можно ли без них обойтись?

Update (код теста):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Map from './Map';

it('renders Map without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<Map />, div);
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
});
```

Comment: То, что вы привели в впоросе код компонента конечно же полезно, но по-хорошему нужно добавить код теста. Могу подсказать, что нужно проинициализировать глобальный объект `window.ymaps` .Тут как бы можно пойти вот таким подходом: `global.window = jest.fn(() => {
  ymaps: { ready: ... }
});` Инициализируем глобальный  `window`, у него `ymaps`, а у него `ready`. Либо запихиваем туда объект из Yandex.Maps. Короче, нужно, чтобы у вас был `ymaps` в `window`. Этот код помещать перед запуском теста, можно в `beforeEach`, а можно и в `describe` внутри теста перед `it`

Comment: Добавил код теста в описание вопроса. Кажется идею вашу понял, завтра проверю на практике. Большое спасибо.

Comment: Подскажите, что должно стоять на месте троеточия, после 'ready: ...'

Comment: Ну смотрите, если вы будете делать фейк - то там должна быть функция, принимающая один параметр типа функция, и насколько я понял, вызывающий внутри эту функцию. Но для вашего случая лучше подсунуть объект ymaps из библиотеки яндекс карт (мне кажется, хотя если он вам там не сильно нужен, то фейк в самый раз)

Comment: Сделал так: 
global.window = jest.fn(() => { 
  ymaps: { 
    ready: (fn) => fn() 
  }
});

it('renders Map without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<Map />, div);
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
});

но не помогло.

Comment: Положите это в `beforeEach`, либо попробуйте без `jest.fn`, просто наколбасить объект `global.window = { ymaps: { ready: (fn) => fn() } };` Видимо `jest.fn` отрабатывает не сразу, поэтому на момент запуска теста целевого объекта еще нет.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте следующее решение:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Map from './Map';

describe('Map', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    window.ymaps = {
      ready: jest.fn(() => {})
    };
  });

  it('renders Map without crashing', () => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    ReactDOM.render(<Map />, div);
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
  });
});
```